# Android checkbox multiselected issue

Tags: android-layout

I did listview with set of rows. Each rows having a checkbox. If I am clicking one checkbox, another checkbox also checked. What I will do to avoid this ? Anyone knows help me..

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the problems with CheckBoxes in a ListView you can take a Boolean array initialized false in the beginning and then making true the corresponding position in the array where checkbox is checked in the ListView. This will not cause a trouble in checked state of checkboxes when you move forward and backward in your application or scroll the ListView.

Here is how to set checkboxstate is the boolean array:

```
 holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                            checkBoxState[pos] = true;
                        else
                            checkBoxState[pos] = false;

                    }
                });
```

and then this will keep the checkboxes checked when you scroll and the state will not automatically change:

```
holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[pos]);
```

Comment: use it in your getView() method.If you don't know the use of holder then please study your Custom ListView thoroughly.

Comment: public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView; 
         vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainlist_item,null);
        
        ImageView imgview=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.nameid); 
        TextView view = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.deptid);
        
        
        imgview.setImageBitmap(imgs.get(position));
        artist.setText(empname.get(position));
        view.setText(empdept.get(position));
        return vi;
    }

Comment: This is my code.. Its working for single checked. But unchecked while scrolling up and down..

Comment: please post the code in proper format....is not readable plus post your logcat....I am posting my code...understand it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code:

```
 public class Favourites extends Activity {
        ListView list;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.listfavourites);
            initcomponents();

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {  
                }
            });
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> hmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hmap.put("itemname", "ItemName" + i);
                hmap.put("price", "Price");
                alist.add(hmap);

            }

            final CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.listitemfavourites, alist);

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        private void initcomponents() {
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listfavourites_lst_list);

        }

        class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {
            Context context;
            boolean[] checkBoxState;
            int textViewResourceId;
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alist;

            public CustomListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> alist) {
                super(context, textViewResourceId);
                this.context = context;
                this.alist = alist;
                this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
                checkBoxState = new boolean[alist.size()];

            }

            public int getCount() {

                return alist.size();
            }

            public View getView(final int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                Holder holder = null;

                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitemfavourites, parent,
                        false);
                holder = new Holder();
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.listitemfavourites_chk_checkbox);
                holder.itemname = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.listitemfavourites_txt_itemname);
                holder.price = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.listitemfavourites_txt_price);
                holder.lin_background = (LinearLayout) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.favourites_lin_top);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

                holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();

                holder.itemname.setText(alist.get(pos).get("itemname"));
                holder.price.setText(alist.get(pos).get("price"));
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(checkBoxState[pos]);
                if (pos == 0) {
                    holder.lin_background
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_celltop);
                } else if (pos == (alist.size() - 1) && alist.size() != 1) {

                    holder.lin_background
                            .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_cellbottom);
                }
                holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
                            checkBoxState[pos] = true;
                        else
                            checkBoxState[pos] = false;

                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }

            class Holder {
                TextView itemname, price;
                CheckBox checkbox;
                LinearLayout lin_background;
            }
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are recycling the view by the condition if(view==null) remove this.

Comment: Its working.. But If I am scrolling the listview means, the checkbox will unchecked automatically