# Checkbox-Not selected the Current positon

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am using checkbox in an listview,while click the checkbox it has to select the content in the row.But is not taking taking the current position.But is not select the current positon first and second time is not selecting anything.Is not selecting the current position,Its selecting randomly.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item2);
        lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mDbHelper = new GinfyDbAdapter(this);
        share = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnget);
        btnadd1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        lv = getListView();
        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                for(int i=0;i<mCheckStates.size();i++)

                {
                    if(mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                         result.append("Title:");
                         result.append(bb.get(i));
                         result.append("\n");
                         result.append("Content:");
                         result.append(aa.get(i));
                         result.append("\n");
                    }

                }
               // }
                 showAlertView(result.toString().trim());

            }

        });

        btnadd1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                createProject();


            }

        });

        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());


    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void fillData() {
        mDbHelper.open();      
        Cursor projectsCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllProjects();

        int count = projectsCursor.getCount();
        Log.i(".................",""+count);
        if (projectsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
              do {

                  int col1 = projectsCursor.getColumnIndex("title");
                  String title = projectsCursor.getString(col1 );         
                  bb.add(title);              

                      int col2 = projectsCursor.getColumnIndex("content");
                                String content = projectsCursor.getString(col2 );         
                            aa.add(content);
              } while (projectsCursor.moveToNext());

        }
        //startManagingCursor(projectsCursor);


        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE,GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT,GinfyDbAdapter.CATEGORY_COLUMN_DATE};

        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text22,R.id.text11,R.id.date};
        dataAdapter = new CustomAdapter (YourPrayerActivity .this, R.layout.row2, projectsCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(dataAdapter);



        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return mDbHelper.fetchProjectByName(constraint.toString());
            }
        });



        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text11);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);



    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                //btnaudioprayer.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();
            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }




    private void createProject() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, AddyourprayerActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);  
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();
    }


    private void speakOut() {

        // String text = txtText.getText().toString();
        // String text = "Android speech";

        tts.speak(typed, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private ListView lv;




        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
                 {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(c.getCount());

        }


         @Override
            public void bindView(View view, Context context, final Cursor cursor){


             if (view != null) {
                int row_id = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");  //Your row id (might need to replace)
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text22);
                final TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text11);
                TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                int col1 = cursor.getColumnIndex("title");
                final String title = cursor.getString(col1 );
                int col2 = cursor.getColumnIndex("content");
                final String content = cursor.getString(col2 );
                int col3 = cursor.getColumnIndex("date");
                final String date = cursor.getString(col3);
                cb.setTag(cursor.getPosition());
                cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(cursor.getPosition()+1, false));
                cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

                tv.setText( title);
                tv1.setText( content);
                tv2.setText(date);

                ImageButton button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sms1);
                button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();
                    sb2.append("Title:");
                        sb2.append(Html.fromHtml(title));
                        sb2.append(",Content:");
                        sb2.append(Html.fromHtml(content));
                        sb2.append("\n");
                        String strContactList1 = (sb2.toString().trim());
                        sendsmsdata(strContactList1);
                    }
                });

                ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.mail1);
                button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        StringBuffer sb3 = new StringBuffer();
                    sb3.append("Title:");
                        sb3.append(Html.fromHtml(title));
                        sb3.append(",Content:");
                        sb3.append(Html.fromHtml(content));
                        sb3.append("\n");
                        String strContactList2 = (sb3.toString().trim());
                        sendmaildata(strContactList2);
                    }
                });

                ImageButton button2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnaudioprayer1);
                button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        //ADD STUFF HERE you know which row is clicked. and which button
                        typed = content;
                        speakOut();
                    }
                });
             }





            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, parent, false);

                bindView(v,context,cursor);
                return v;
            }

            public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

            }
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked); 
}
```

while click the checkbox,and then after have to click share button it will shows sms or email,if we click sms,in that content what are the things we checked that content has to be there in msg content.

I checked in debug,if i select the first or second row its taking or otherwise if i selected thirdrow first its not taking the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a count variable as a class member

```
int count;
```

Then in `fillData`

```
count = projectsCursor.getCount();
```

SO when you click on a button

```
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            if(count>0) // check if count is greater than o
                            // count can be 0 if you don't select any check box
            {
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)

            {Log.i("checked content Inside on click of share ",""+aa.get(i));
                if(mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                {
                     result.append("Title:");
                     result.append(bb.get(i));

                     result.append("\n");
                     result.append("Content:");
                     result.append(aa.get(i));
                     result.append("\n");

                }

            }
            }
```

You are using a SparseBoolean array which is true for row that you check. Then you retrieve the data based on the checked items.

Here's the sample from which i picked upon

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

What you were doing is you were not going through the whole list of items to check if the checkbox was checked.

```
        for(int i=0;i<mCheckStates.size();i++) // this was the problem
```

if only two items are checked you will get the first two.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problems with CheckBoxes in a ListView you can take a Boolean array initialized false in the beginning and then making true the corresponding position in the array where checkbox is checked in the ListView.Please refer to this demo here:

[Android checkbox multiselected issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673108/android-checkbox-multiselected-issue/18673407#18673407)

Comment: i didnt use any holder here,i used bindview like getview. http://pastie.org/8338613 here i post my full code

Comment: so why not implement the logic in bindView. It was just a sample so that you get an idea of how it works.

Comment: i didnt get you,can you explain in my code,how to do to avoid that one

Comment: You can take a Boolean array with all the indexes set to false and make the corresponding checked true and setChecked those corresponding locations in the list which have true. And why are you using bindView method in listview when it is deprecated.

Comment: how to do to avoid that one,Here in all row i am giving an checkbox,if the people will select 3 checkbox it has to take the three content in that row,and click share button it will shows two option sms,email.in sms msg content that three row content has to there.

Comment: try using the demo...use getView method instead....It will solve the issue for sure.

Comment: ya i used boolean also,can you check that link where i mention my full code

Comment: actually bindview and getview both are same only

Comment: ,the thing is that it will take only if first row selected only.

Answer (score 0):

Why not you use arrayAdapter?

Have a look at this link. Hope it helps you out.

< http://androidcocktail.blogspot.in/2012/04/adding-checkboxes-to-custom-listview-in.html>

Comment: then i have to change into bindview into getview ah dude,what is the difference

Comment: ,is this problem can we use problem on bindview

Answer (score 0):

As the behavior or getview() method that it recreate view everytime whenever you scroll, so have to maintain position using setTag & getTag, even store selected checked into array with proper position.

Try below example, you can replace toggle button with check box.

[Getview Method Wierd in Listview](http://robinhood87.blogspot.in/2013/03/getview-method-wierd-in-listview-its.html)