# checkboxes not checked properly. Android

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

I have implemented a cutomAdapter for listview. I have implemented some checkboxes inside it. The problem is when I check the checkbox at the first position, some other checkbox gets checked.

Here is my adapter...

```
    public class AScustomadapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
int i = 0;

public AScustomadapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList){
    mListItems = arrayList;
    //get the layout inflater
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    // create a ViewHolder reference
    ViewHolder holder;

    //check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);

        holder.b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        holder.cb1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        // the setTag is used to store the data within this view
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
        holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }

    //get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
    final String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);

    if (stringItem != null) {
        if (holder.itemName != null) {
            //set the item name on the TextView
            holder.itemName.setText(stringItem);
        }
    }

    //button
    holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ASreviewCA.class);
            i.putExtra("sItem", stringItem);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //view
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (position == 0) { 
            }
            Log.d("LIST", "Selected item # " + position);
        }
    });

    holder.cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isChecked) {
                i++;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(), String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

            }else {
                i--;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(), String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

    //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
    return view;
}
/**
 * Static class used to avoid the calling of "findViewById" every time the getView() method is called,
 * because this can impact to your application performance when your list is too big. The class is static so it
 * cache all the things inside once it's created.
 */
private static class ViewHolder {

    protected TextView itemName;
    protected Button b1;
    protected CheckBox cb1;

}
```

}

Comment: when you clicked on row `x` , `I` next row and so on also changed?

Comment: does it get auto checked.. when you scroll the listview ?

Comment: Actually when I check a box and then uncheck it, it gets checked automatically after I scroll the listview.

Answer (score 1):

maintain one ArrayList for checked positions in Adapter class and check for the checked positions in getView() method. like ...

```
private ArrayList<Integer> checkedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
.......

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
// create a ViewHolder reference
ViewHolder holder;

//check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
if (view == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();

    view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);

    holder.b1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    holder.cb1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

    // the setTag is used to store the data within this view
    view.setTag(holder);
} else {
    // the getTag returns the viewHolder object set as a tag to the view
    holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
}

//get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
final String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);

if (stringItem != null) {
    if (holder.itemName != null) {
        //set the item name on the TextView
        holder.itemName.setText(stringItem);
    }
}

//button
holder.b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ASreviewCA.class);
        i.putExtra("sItem", stringItem);
        v.getContext().startActivity(i);
    }
});

//view
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position == 0) { 
        }
        Log.d("LIST", "Selected item # " + position);
    }
});

holder.cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (isChecked) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(), "Checked = "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            checkedIndices.add(position);

        }else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(buttonView.getContext(), "Unchecked = "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            checkedIndices.remove((Integer)position));
        }
    }
});
if(checkedIndices.contains((Integer)position) {
    holder.cb1.setChecked(true);
} else {
    holder.cb1.setChecked(false);
}

//this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
return view;
```

}

write one method in Adapter class like...

```
 public int getTotalCheckedCount() {
      return checkedIndices.size();
 }
```

Comment: I think your code must be get `OutOfBoundsArrayIndex` while `checkedIndices.remove((Integer)position));`, because you must first find the position in the list and then remove that,

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. I now want to keep track of the number of checked items throughout the whole view. I don't want the length of the list to affect the count of the checked boxes. Can you edit the code a bit for that also? Much appreciated.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan No. it will throw NPE. have you checked that?

Comment: @MohammadSohaib can you elaborate your need. I didn't get you. If I understood, I will editcode...

Comment: @GopalRao if you checked twentith row, you add 20 into list that is right but if you want remove that you remove twentith row of list that your list just have 1 row, can you answer my sample?

Comment: (In very simple words) If I check 3 boxes, I want a function to return 3. If I check 10 boxes, I want a function to return 10. Can you edit?

Comment: Gave ArrayIndexOutOfBound error on this line "checkedIndices.remove(listPos);"

Comment: first typecast listPos to **Integer** like

    Integer pos = (Integer)listPos;
    checkedIndices.remove(pos);

Comment: Where should I do the typecasting? Inside which function or loop or ...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42022/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-mohammad-sohaib)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the problems with CheckBoxes in a ListView you can take a Boolean array initialized false in the beginning and then making true the corresponding position in the array where checkbox is checked in the ListView. This will not cause a trouble in checked state of checkboxes when you move forward and backward in your application or scroll the ListView.You can check my sample code here:

[Android checkbox multiselected issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673108/android-checkbox-multiselected-issue/18741798#18741798)